# Inserting a trace property into a divergent loop integral - what exactly is being done here?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, integration

I'm reading through "H. Kleinert and V. Schulte-Frohlinde" notes for  "Critical Properties of $\phi^{4}$-Theories", and I've reached this point in the lecture notes:

$\ $

[image]

$\ $

The trace property being referred to is using $\sum_{\mu} \delta_{\mu\mu} = D$ to write integrals like:
$$
\int \frac{d^{D}p}{(2\pi)^{D}} p_{\mu} p_{\nu} f(\mathbf{p}^{2}) = \frac{1}{D} \int \frac{d^{D}p}{(2\pi)^{D}} \delta_{\mu\nu} \mathbf{p}^{2} f(\mathbf{p}^{2})
$$

I am really confused how the authors use this "trace property" to go from (8.73) to (8.75). I get lost after I replace a $1$ underneath the integral with a "$\frac{1}{2D}\left( \frac{\partial p_{1}^{\mu}}{\partial p_{1}^{\mu}} + \frac{\partial p_{2}^{\mu}}{\partial p_{2}^{\mu}} \right)$". How do we get a factor of $\frac{1}{D-3}$ in the end? Are we differentiating somehow?

Can someone break down for me what is happening there? I've been scratching my head at this for too long.